# Notebook displaying marks of text from programs opened for too long?

Tags: display, pixels

Using my Macbook Pro Retina, when I have the same program somewhere on the screen for too long and close it, I can see a mark of it's letters on that place of the screen. Is that common or a fabrication problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a widely occurring issue with Retina screens. See here for a discussion on Apple's forums. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4034848?start=0&tstart=0

It looks like your best bet is to try to take the machine into Apple for a replacement, and in the meantime use a screensaver set to come on in a relatively short amount of idle time (5 minutes should be good).